# Entity Model Not Being Updated on SaveChanges

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, save

I have a misunderstanding somewhere with the Entity Framework.  This code is from my unit testing:

```
Public Sub UpdateRosterLinkTest()
    Dim target As PlayerAdmin = New PlayerAdmin()

    target.PlayerAdminManager = playerAdminTestManager
    target.Team = playerAdminTestManager.GetAirForceMensBB()

    playerAdminTestManager.resetRosterLink(target)
    Assert.IsNull(target.Team.RosterLink)

    Dim playerAdmin As PlayerAdmin = New PlayerAdmin()
    playerAdmin.TeamId = 12434
    playerAdmin.RosterLink = "Roster Link"

    playerAdmin.UpdateRosterLink()

    Dim team As DAL.Team = playerAdminTestManager.GetAirForceMensBB()
    Assert.AreEqual("Roster Link", team.RosterLink)

End Sub
```

I'm creating a `PlayerAdmin`, which is a model class.  `target.Team` is an Entity object.  What I do is reset the `RosterLink` field in the `Team` just to make sure our test starts out at the same place.  Then I call the `UpdateRosterLink()` function.  That looks like:

```
Function UpdateRosterLink() As Integer
        If (PlayerAdminManager Is Nothing) Then
            PlayerAdminManager = New PlayerAdminManager()
        End If

        Team = PlayerAdminManager.GetTeamByTeamId(TeamId)
        Team.RosterLink = RosterLink
        Dim numberOfChanges As Integer = PlayerAdminManager.SaveChanges()
        Return numberOfChanges
    End Function
```

When I run this code, I can see the changes saved to the SQL Server this pulls from (`RosterLink` = Roster Link, like I set in the unit test).

However, my unit test is failing, because `team.RosterLink` is still `Nothing`.  The function `GetAirForceMensBB()` returns the `Team` with TeamId = 12434:

```
Function GetAirForceMensBB() As DAL.Team
    Return (From team In Container.Teams Where team.TeamId = 12434).SingleOrDefault
End Function
```

I'm sure I'm using the entity framework incorrectly and it probably has something to do with the fact that I am calling the `PlayerAdminTestManager` in different places, but I don't understand why.  Although, I set the `PlayerAdminManager` to be the `PlayerAdminTestManager`.  `PlayerAdminTestManager` extends `PlayerAdminManager`, fyi.

Why is `team.RosterLink` not showing the update from `UpdateRosterLink`?

Thanks

**EDIT**
`Container` is my `ObjectContext`.  This is how I access the information stored in the database.  `Container.Teams` represents my `Teams` table.

Comment: @AdamTuliper - it's my `Teams` table from my database

Comment: are you sure there is anything in that collection? set a breakpoint. Also ensure there is one where the id=12434. If you change SingleOrDefaiult to just Single() it will blow up if you don't have any teams, and then you'll know thats where the issue is.

Comment: It's not a null pointer exception.  `team` is defined, it's just that RosterLink is still null from my call to `resetRosterLink(target)`.  It's some sort of caching problem.  If I do: `playerAdminTestManager = New PlayerAdminTestManager()` immediately before I assign `team` it works as expected.  I guess I just really have an error in my logic about the ObjectContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was referencing different instantiations of the Container (each manager created its own).  Thus, the entity items were not attached to anything.

Doh!